# Solr UninvertingReader getNumericDocValues doesn't seem to work for fields that are not stored or indexed

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a defined field in my schema.xml that is a simple float that is not stored nor indexed as follows:

```
<field name="boost" type="float" docValues="true" indexed="false" stored="false" required="false" multiValued="false"/>
```

In Solr 4 I was able to get the float value the following way:

```
FieldCache.Floats docBoosts = FieldCache.DEFAULT.getFloats(context.reader(), FieldName.Boost, false);
float boost = docBoosts == null ? 1.0f : docBoosts.get(doc)
return boost == 0.0f ? 1.0f : boost
```

In Solr 5 I tried to do this instead of FieldCache:

```
 NumericDocValues docBoosts = DocValues.getNumeric(context.reader(),  FieldName.Boost)
```

However this approach didn't work, as the UninvertingReader.getType fails to detect that this field is a float an instead provides me with a NumericDocValue from Lucene54DocValuesProducer that changes the value of 0.95f to 1.06451437E9.

Has anyone found a similar issue, and if so could you tell me what am I missing?

Comment: I got a reply to this question here: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-UninvertingReader-getNumericDocValues-doesn-t-seem-to-work-for-fields-that-are-not-stored-or-ind-td4251881.html#a4252035

Comment: I added Float.intBitsToFloat((int)val) to the value returned from the NumericDocValues get and converted the value to 0.95f